# How can I get my Steam account back?

Tags: steam

I was in the middle of playing Team Fortress 2, and I just got hacked in-game.  Steam just logged out for no exact reason, and I got kicked out of the application.  I tried logging in, and there was an error.  It's a premium account, so that's probably why somebody hacked it.  Is there any way I can get it back?

Comment: Do you have 2 factor authentication, and what is the specific error when you try to log in?

Comment: Stop reading Stack Exchange and contact Valve ASAP. Give them as many details as possible.

Comment: Thanks for your help... I finally found out how to contact Valve.  Person named Earl said that my account was compromised and I got it back.  Thanks so much BTW :D

Comment: @Daneolog What's a premium account? Never heard about that before

Comment: @Artery In combination with Team Fortress 2: Team Fortress 2 is a Free to Play game. Accounts that have never bought anything from the TF2 store have certain limitations within TF2. Buying something from the TF2 store will upgrade the account to premium, with more backpack space etc.

Answer (score 2):

For people finding this question via Google. Follow the steps outlined in [this Steam Support article](https://help.steampowered.com/en/wizard/HelpWithAccountStolen) in that exact order:

1. Scan (and secure) your computer. Make sure there are no viruses on your computer, and make sure your network and connected devices are all safe. Doing anything on a compromised computer will only make thing worse.
2. Secure your email. Make sure that no-one is able to get access to your email. Always use a completely unique password for your email that you never use anywhere else. Someone can reset all your passwords using your email and authorize an aweful lot of things with it, which makes your email the most critical thing to keep safe. Use 2FA with your email if you have not set it up yet.
3. Change your Steam password by following the link on that page (or go to [this link](https://help.steampowered.com/en/wizard/HelpWithLoginInfo?reset=1&issueid=408) if it still works).

If you are using the Steam app, do not authorize anything that was not done by you. Ever. Do not give the code generated by the app to anyone, and only enter it on the official Steam website.